# Can't login and sign up in my django-site

Tags: python, django, heroku, python-3.6, django-2.0

After deploying on heroku i faced the following problem when trying to log in to my account:

```
relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
```

All files in bin directory includes the following line in the header:

```
#!/home/far/git/django_site.git/Django_work/django_structure/bin/python
```

Full logs:

```
ProgrammingError at /accounts/login/

relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                         ^

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://stripe-like.herokuapp.com/accounts/login/
Django Version:     2.0.3
Exception Type:     ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    

relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                         ^

Exception Location:     /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 85
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version:     3.6.4
Python Path:    

['/app',
'/app/django_structure/src',
'/app/.heroku/python/bin',
'/app',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python36.zip',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
```

Using django.sites(SITE_ID=1) did not lead to change. Even after adding the line SITE_ADD=1 no migration occur resulting in the error.

**Update:**

After deleting db.sqlite3 i add my postgresql db into settings file. And i found `django_site` table in there after migrating:

```
-- Table: public.django_site

-- DROP TABLE public.django_site;

CREATE TABLE public.django_site
(
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('django_site_id_seq'::regclass),
domain character varying(100) NOT NULL,
name character varying(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT django_site_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT django_site_domain_a2e37b91_uniq UNIQUE (domain)
)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.django_site
OWNER TO joe;

-- Index: public.django_site_domain_a2e37b91_like

-- DROP INDEX public.django_site_domain_a2e37b91_like;

CREATE INDEX django_site_domain_a2e37b91_like
ON public.django_site
USING btree
(domain COLLATE pg_catalog."default" varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `SITE_ID` into **settings.py** something like

```
SITE_ID=1
```

and then run the command :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**If this doesn't work:**

Try to manually migrate sites app before any other migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate sites
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error occurs due to empty migration folder.

You need to run:

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate

I hope your problem will be solved.

**If it does not work :**

Then manually delete all .pyc files from migration folder. And delete database. Then create database. And run makemigrations and migrate command.

Comment: So umm... What should I do with the preinstalled sqlite3? I mean, I can't even open it properly. But I also have postgresql installed in the system itself. I would put it in `DATABASES` instead of sqlite3, but I don't know exactly what rows should be created in the postgresql database.

Comment: You need to check database name from settings.py. that database should be created in postgresql . You can check database in pg admin 3.
After that , you need to right click on database. Then delete database. Then you should create database manually in pg admin 3. 
Then delete all files in migration folder except init.py.
Then run makemigrations and migrate command.

Comment: Now i getting this: `relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "auth_user" WHERE UPPER("auth_user"."...`

Comment: Could you send me your urls.py and settings.py ?

Comment: Of course. Here it is: [https://github.com/AlfredMulder/Django_work], django_structure->src->django_structure.